# Grails Domain class property Set failed Validation

Tags: setter, grails-domain-class, grails-validation

I have problem with a setter in grails. I have two properties beforeTax and afterTax. I only want to store one property in the db beforeTax. In the ui I want the user to enter either before or after tax. So I made the afterTax a transient property like this:

```
double getAfterTax(){
  return beforeTax * tax
}

void setAfterTax(double value){
  beforeTax = value / tax
}
```

When I now enter the after tax value and want to save the object the validation fails (before tax can not be an empty value)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to compute beforeTax based on the value of afterTax?

You could use the event handler methods beforeXXX() where XXX is Validate, Insert, and Update to compute beforeTax.  Then beforeTax's constraint can be nullable:false.

```
def beforeValidate() {
   computeBeforeTax() 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to flag one property as transient, in order to prevent GORM from trying to save this variable into DB. Try to add this line into your domain class, which contains `afterTax`.

```
static transients = ['afterTax']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I havent written the question understandably. I have made it transient already. see in question (So I made the afterTax a transient property)

The problem is that the data binding tells me that an empty property (beforeTax) is not valid. That is true, so to solve my problem I made the beforeTax a nullable value and now it works.

That is not realy want I wanted because the value should not be nullable but it is the best I got at the moment.

Comment: i guess i need the piece of code, which shows the creation/save of your object. otherwise i cannot help you any further, sorry ;)